# JPA Repository Lob column

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Is it possible to implement JPA-repository with filtering by lob-column?

I have the following code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBJECT_IDENTIFIER")      
public class SubjectIdentifier implements Serializable {

     @Id
     @Column(name = "SUBJECT_IDENTIFIER_ID")
     private long subjectIdentifierIid;

     @Lob
     @Column(name = "SOR_BP_GUID", columnDefinition="BLOB NOT NULL")
     private byte[] bpGuid;

     //getter/setter
}


public interface SubjectIdentifierRepository extends JpaRepository<SubjectIdentifier, Long> {

   @Query("select si from SubjectIdentifier  si where si.bpGuid= :bpGuid")
   SubjectRepository findByBpGuid(@Param("bpGuid") byte[] bpGuid);

}
```

//test

```
SubjectRepository byBpGuid = subjectIdentifierRepository.findByBpGuid("D9E70D24567E4DAE8FD3ED5898579092".getBytes());
```

but I can not find objects from database. 
Do I have to implement this query by other way?

Comment: Your column name (in the DB, and as defined in the annotation) is `SOR_BP_GUID` but your SQL statement is looking for `si.bpGuid` -  I think it should be `si.sor_bp_guid`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, provided that your database supports it.

I recommend writing your query as shown below, as the requirement can be fully resolved without use of the `@Query` annotation.

```
SubjectRepository findOneByBpGuid(@Param("bpGuid") byte[] bs);
```

I'm a bit curious on the `columnDefinition` specification: is the db column set to the wrong type without that? I would prefer this statement over the use of `columnDefinition` if possible. This will leave the configuration database agnostic.

```
@Column(name = "SOR_BP_GUID", nullable = false)
```

See Also: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation